# Execute specific blocks of code based on which key on the keyboard is pressed

Tags: c#

I am very new to the programming world and recently dove into c#. I don't want to waste your time so I'll get right to it. I wanted to create a program just to test my knowledge, and thought I could attempt to execute specific blocks of code based on which key on the keyboard is pressed by the user. I tried doing this by creating an event handler that contained if statements, but then realized I didn't know how to have the event handler active in the program.

For example, and as you can see in the below snippet, after the WriteLine in Line 5 lets say I wanted to raise the EventKeyPress event so that it waits for user input and reads the key they have pressed and reacts accordingly, how would I do that?

Again, I'm almost a complete beginner and have searched around for explanations about event handlers for hours and still can't wrap my head around what I am supposed to do or if I am even using the event handler correctly. Thanks in advance!

```
    static void Main(); 
    {
        if (search == "Ball")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit or backspace to return to the search bar")
            // RIGHT HERE
        }

        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, I don't recognize {0}", search);
        }



        void EventKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1;)
            {
                if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
                {
                    // exit app
                }

                else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
                {
                    // go back to search
                }

                else
                {
                    i = 0; // error
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If this is a console application, it's not based around an eventing concept.  Pressing keys does not raise an event - you need to use `Console.ReadLine` to solicit keyboard input from the user.

Comment: Is this a windows app?  A web app? Console?  WPF?

Comment: @BJMyers ohh, I was under the impression that there were other ways to solicit keyboard input from the user, thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you're asking for something that involves `Threading` which is not a beginner thing to accomplish at all. The best way to do this for a beginner is to ask for a prompt, then accept as an input. For example.

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello, what's your name?");
string nameStr = Console.ReadLine();

Console.WriteLine($"Hello, {nameStr}");
```

You can then use your variable and apply it to an if/while or whatever kind of conditional.

```
if (nameStr == "Matt"){
//Do This Code.
```

}

Once you have that code, add a sequential method that will ask the user to return to the main menu or whatever you want it to do.

```
Main.ReturnMenu(); //Or whatever you want to use.
```